# Error "Expected method 'color_frecuente' to be defined as" en plataforma de enseñanza de Python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un curso de Python y no sé cómo hacer estas preguntas. ¿Alguien me las puede responder?, por favor.

> Suponga que tiene una lista de colores repetidos y desordenados, estos pueden ser: azul, rojo, verde y amarillo. Desea saber cual de esos colores es el que más se repite.
>
> Escriba una función `color_frecuente` que reciba como argumento a una lista de strings llamada lista y retorne el string más repetido y el número de ocurrencias del mismo.
>
> Por ejemplo para la lista:
>
> ```
> ['azul', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 
> 'verde', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'azul', 'azul', 'verde', 'verde', 
> 'verde', 'amarillo', 'amarillo']
> ```
>
> Debe retornar:
>
> ```
> "verde", 8
> ```
>
> En caso de que haya varios colores con el máximo número, se retornará con la siguiente prioridad: azul, rojo, verde, amarillo. Es decir, por ejemplo si la lista es `l = ['rojo', 'rojo', 'azul', azul']`, la función debe retornar `"azul", 2`.

Este es el código que llevo y me dice que tengo que devolver a verde 8 y lo devuelve, pero me sale error:

```
def obtener_color_frecuente(colores, lista_prioridad):
    contador = {}
    for color in colores:
        if color in contador:
            contador[color] += 1 # incrementamos si existe el color
        else:
            contador[color] = 1 # creamos un nuevo item con el key del color y el valor inicial de 1
    m = max(contador.values()) # obtenemos el max de repeticiones
    color_seleccionado = [key for key, value in contador.items() if value == m] # seleccionamos los colores que cumplen con el maximo
    if len(color_seleccionado) > 1: # verificamos si existe mas de un maximo
        color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x)) # obtenemos el elemento segun la prioridad
    else:
         color_seleccionado = color_seleccionado[0]
    return color_seleccionado, m

prioridad = ["azul","rojo","verde","amarillo"]
colores = ['azul', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'azul', 'azul', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'amarillo', 'amarillo']
print(obtener_color_frecuente(colores, prioridad))
```

[image: Captura de pantalla del mensaje de error]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Mucho mejor ahora, el error que muestras puede ser un error de una plataforma de e-learning? Si es así, lo que te estaría diciendo es que se está esperando una función `color_frecuente()` que tiene un único parámetro de entrada que es la lista, sin embargo tu función parece tener otro nombre y recibe más parámetros

Comment: creo que ya esta bien no estoy seguro

Comment: Voto el cierre por no poder reproducir este problema. El código funciona correctamente. Aparentemente ha definido la función con un nombre erróneo (`obtener_color_frecuente`) y la plataforma le pide que use el solicitado en la pregunta (`color_frecuente`).

Answer (score 1):

Eso es un error de la plataforma donde estas realizando el ejercicio no de python, la plataforma te pide que cambies la estructura de tu funcion a esa especificamente, puedes agregar la lista de prioridad dentro de la funcion

```
def color_frecuente(lista):
    prioridad = ['azul','rojo',...]
    ...
```